# tmux start search by typing

Tags: tmux

How I can make tmux start search when I typing something (like in vim)?

Actually, I have (vi mode for tmux):

- enter copy mode:  [
- enter search mode:/
- I type something, then press "Enter". This is very very boring type "Enter" every time, after each change of search pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tmux does not support incremental search at this time, but [a request for this feature](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3445937&group_id=200378&atid=973265) has been filed.